# Ninject не может создать обьект

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, ninject

При попытке создать обьект через контейнер `Ninject` вылетает `exception` : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Метод с класса `NinjectDependencyResolver`

```
private void AddBindings()
        {
            var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new TagProfile());
            });
            var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
            _kernel.Bind<BlogDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
            _kernel.Bind<IRepository<Tag>, Repository<Tag>>();
            _kernel.Bind<IMapper>().ToConstant(mapper);

            var repository = _kernel.Get<IRepository<Tag>>();// вылетает exception
            _kernel.Bind<ITagService, TagService>();
        }
```

**Класс Repository**

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly BlogDbContext _db;

    public Repository(BlogDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Не знаю важно ли это, но репозиторий с его интерфейсом находится в одной сборке, а регистрация `Ninject` в другой.

Comment: Вы используете EntityFramework? По идее у вас должен быть класс, который наследует `BlogDbContext`. Назовем его EntityModel, тогда для `Ninject` будет следующий вызов `_kernel.Bind<BlogDbContext>().To<EntityModel>().InRequestScope();`

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, `BlogDbContext` это класс которые наследует `IdentityDbContext`. Сам контекст резолвится без проблем, а вот репозиторий нет.

Comment: Погодите, а разве это `_kernel.Bind<IRepository<Tag>, Repository<Tag>>();` верное объявление и потом дальше строка `_kernel.Bind<ITagService, TagService>();` ? Вы для этих классов не биндите реализацию. Могу предположить, что должно быть `_kernel.Bind<IRepository<Tag>>().To<Repository<Tag>>();`

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, Спасибо, в этом и была проблема! Может вы знаете ответ на еще один вопрос: если я для контекста делаю `InRequestScope()`, нужно ли мне это делать и для репозитория и для сервиса?

Comment: @Lightness кстати, делать BlogDbContext с временем жизни InRequestScope - это плохая идея. BlogDbContext (и вообще контекст в EF) - это реализация Repository + Unit Of Work. Unit Of Work должен жить ровно одну бизнес-операцию, а это не совсем то же, что "один http-ный запрос". Проблема выстрелит, например, при попытке записать ошибку при обработке запроса в лог в базе. Или на методах вида "проимпортировать несколько записей" - один контекст заставит вас работать по принципу "или все записи импортируются, или вообще ни одной".

Comment: @Lightness я к тому, что раз вы решили использовать EF - используйте его полноценно, и как Repository, и как Unit Of Work. Иначе обязательно выстрелит. Хотя, на мелких простых проектах может и обойтись.

Comment: @PashaPash, Проект пишу чисто в учебных целей, чтобы получше разобраться с `Ninject`. А какой тогда лучше использовать метод если не `InRequestScope `?

Comment: @PashaPash, по поводу `EF` согласен, да и без репозитория в разы удобней с базой работать. Только как тогда писать юнит-тесты для контроллеров, тестить на реальной базе?

Comment: @Lightness обычно делают две связанных обертки поверх EF - чисто  репозиторий (как у вас), для локализации запросов + unit of work для контроля времени жизни контекста. Посмотрите https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2015/11/01/survey-of-entity-framework-unit-of-work-patterns/, подходы Unit of Work Repository Manager + Instantiated Unit of Work. Ну или просто поищите реализации UoW поверх EF - там примерно везде одинаковый подход. Но для учебных целей и для мелких проектов - это слишком сложно, можно и context per request оставить.

Comment: @PashaPash, Спасибо за ссылку, хорошая статья.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что в экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

В этих двух строчках

```
_kernel.Bind<IRepository<Tag>, Repository<Tag>>();
_kernel.Bind<ITagService, TagService>();
```

Вы "говорите" IoC-контейнеру, что при запросе `IRepository<Tag>` или `Repository<Tag>`, необходимо вернуть реализацию, но не указываете ее.

Правильным будет следующий вызов.

```
_kernel.Bind<IRepository<Tag>>().To<Repository<Tag>>();
_kernel.Bind<ITagService>().To<TagService>();
```

Вы сообщаете IoC-контейнеру, что при запросе `IRepository<Tag>` создать экземпляр класса `Repository<Tag>`. Для второй строки аналогично.

И ответ на вопрос *из комментария*:

> для контекста делаю InRequestScope(), нужно ли мне это делать и для
>   репозитория и для сервиса?

Для репозитория и Сервиса не нужно делать `InRequestScope()`, только для контекста `BlogDbContext`

---

**UPD**

> Не знаю важно ли это, но репозиторий с его интерфейсом находится в
>   одной сборке, а регистрация Ninject в другой.

Не важно, главное указать ссылка на сборку в которой лежит репозиторий и интерфейсы